# Why is a suggested edit not available?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Opening https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/8465 results in a 404 message.

[image]

[8464](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/8464) and [8466](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/8466) can be viewed.

What are possible causes for the unavailability of suggested edits (for 10k+ users)?

Comment: Weird. I can see the page as a mod, but not if I'm not logged in. Never seen this happen before.

Comment: @nhinkle Anything interesting about that edit or the edited question/answer? Maybe deleted?

Comment: Nothing notable that I could tell. I'm looking into it.

Comment: @nhinkle Please document them in some way, maybe this is a bug..?

Comment: Sorry - the flags were unrelated on a different post with a similar number.

Comment: It's worth noting that the _original question_ was deleted. I'm not sure why the suggested edit wouldn't show up though if you have 10k.

Comment: @nhinkle If I had to guess I'd say to prevent enumeration. I think this is the reason they don't appear in search results either, and the badges related to deleted posts don't list the posts for which they were awarded either. Still, a canonical answer would be nice.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78064/suggested-edit-on-deleted-question-shown-in-review-feed-but-direct-link-is-brok

Comment: @random Thanks for the link. Do you know whether this is the only possible cause for suggested edits to be unavailable?

Comment: A suggested edit link attached to a deleted post is currently the only reason this happens.

Comment: @random Please consider posting an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the only reasons why a direct link to a suggested edit is not available are:

1. The post it's attached to has been deleted
2. The suggested edit has yet to take place.

In your case, i[t's the former.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78064/suggested-edit-on-deleted-question-shown-in-review-feed-but-direct-link-is-brok)